# display a model when i choose the value "1" with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

```
<div class="col-md-4 bg-warning">状態</div>
                <div class="col-md-8 pd-all-2px">
                    <select class="form-control" id="approvalstate" th:field="*{approvalstate}">
                        <option th:value="0" th:text="未返信"></option> 
                        <option th:value="1" th:text="返信済"></option>
                      </select>
                </div>
```

how to display a model when i choose the value "1" with javascript ?
only for value "1"

Comment: do you have a javascript for this?

Comment: no, i dont know how to make the javascript code

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'll help you out with this one, but please take the time to read the documentation and learn. A great lib that will make it easier to write Javascript is jQuery.

jQuery Way:

```
$('#approvalstate').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 1) {
    //Execute true logic
  } else {
    //Execute false logic
  } 
});
```

Non-jQuery Way:

```
document.getElementById('approvalstate').addEventListener('onchange', function(e) {
    if(e.value == 1) {
    //Execute true logic
  } else {
    //Execute false logic
  } 
});
```

Comment: Please use the Non-jQuery way unless you include the jQuery javascript file (which I don't think you have done).

Comment: @denimaya did this or another answer work for you? If so, please mark the one that helped you the most as the "answer" using the check mark to the left of our post.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthew is almost correct with jQuery way, but this is how it should be used. Otherwise you will get empty return value, as you do not have value in your options.

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $('#approvalstate').change(function() {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');

            if(selected.length) {
                var value = selected.attr('th:value');

                if(value === '1') {
                    console.log('1 selected');
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to solve the issue.
i have used bootstrap model and jquery to handle this issue.

```js
  $('#approvalstate').change(function() {
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

            if(selected != 0) {
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
                console.log(selected);
            }            
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 bg-warning">状態</div>
<div class="col-md-8 pd-all-2px">
<select class="form-control" id="approvalstate">
<option>0</option> 
<option>1</option>
</select>
</div> 
                
                <div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```